# React DateTimePicker with the time of the first use

Tags: react-native, datetimepicker

I have an app for booking things.
The problem I have is that if you use the calendar component several times, time displayed is the time of the first use of my component. What I would like is to display the date when the user clicks from the menu to access the component.

```
export default class Menu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
            <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('Calendar')}>
```

```
export default class Calendar extends Component {
  state = {
    isDateTimePickerVisible: true,
    dateNow : null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
      var myDate = new Date ()
      this.setState( {dateNow: myDate})
  }
...
  render () {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <DateTimePicker
          isVisible={this.state.isDateTimePickerVisible}
          onConfirm={this.handleDatePicked}
          onCancel={() => {   this.hideDateTimePicker,
                              this.props.navigation.navigate('Menu') }}
          titleIOS='When do you want to book' // for iOS only
          mode='datetime'
        />
      </View>
```

My problem is that DateTimPicker displays the date and time when called for the first time. Is there a way to avoid it ?

Comment: what time do you want it to display?

Comment: How do you pass the `dateNow` from state to `DateTimePicker`? Why do you do it only on `componentDidMount`? Isn't there an `onChange` event for the `DateTimePicker`?

Comment: @Mike M: I would like to display the time when the user click on the button to navigate to the component.

Comment: @Vladimir Bogomolov: I don't pass dateNow to DateTimePicker - it automatically set its time. There is a property minimumDate I could use but it is only valid in iOS not Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using `react-native-modal-datetime-picker` in which case you can just pass `date={new Date()}` or whatever date you wish to display initially.

Comment: how to give initial time (not current time) when mode is time?